# How can I list of PID's of all processes running within a directory?

Tags: ps, processes

I want to list all processes that are running in a directory.

For example, let's say 3 three processes are running:

- `/home/myname/myapp/process1`
- `/home/myname/myapp/process2`
- `/home/myname/myapp/anotherprocess`

How would I ask the system: "Give me the PID of all processes running in `/home/myname/myapp`"?

The only way i can think of is

`ps -eo pid,args | grep -i /home/myname/myapp | awk '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ' '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fuser -m /path/to/folder 2>/dev/null` (discards `stderr` from output) or examine the available use cases with `man fuser`

Comment: `fuser -m /home/ndipiazza/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_161`
`/home/ndipiazza/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_161:  1726e  3290rce  3305rce  3512rce  3723rce  3728rce  3738rce  3744rce  3748rce  ...` not sure how to read this

Comment: I updated my answer. I forgot about the stderr output. The PID's are left

Comment: `fuser -m /home/ndipiazza/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_121 2>/dev/null` = `1181 1188 1189 1192 1193 1196 1252 1258 1350 1402 2623 2637 2824 3019 3024 3033 3039 3043 3049 3072 3077 3078 3083 3086 3088 3097 3104 3108 3109 3111 3119 3124 3129` is what it says yet there are only 2 processes running in that folder

Comment: `ps -eo pid,args | grep -i /home/ndipiazza/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_121 | awk '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ' '`
correctly returns 
`10133 19113`

Comment: The `fuser` tool is accurate and does it's inspection of processes in a similar method as `lsof`. You should inspect each process, some may be active child processes spawned by a parent application

Answer (score 4):

Note that your command *does not* list the processes running in a directory.  It lists the processes whose program image files *were found* (by the shell) in that directory and thus listed as such in their 0th command argument (or that happen to have that directory mentioned in their other command arguments).  Those processes are of course not necessarily running in that directory.  I am going to assume that you want what you asked for (given that you did say *running in a directory* three times), not what your command actually did.

Since you have not specified an operating system:

## FreeBSD/TrueOS and OpenBSD

Use the `-f` option to `fstat` to have it filter by filesystem, use the `stat` command to get the inode number of the desired directory (named in   the shell variable `${directory}` as appropriate beforehand), and use `awk` to use the latter as a filter on `wd` entries output by `fstat`:

```
fstat -f "${directory}" | 
awk '{
    if ($4 == "wd" && $6 == '"`stat -f %i \"${directory}\"`"' && !x[$3]++)
        print $3;
}'
```

Run (only) `fstat` as the superuser in order to include other users' processes.

## Linux

Two approaches:

- Use the `-d` option to `lsof` to have it select only `cwd` entries, use the `stat` command and some `dc` post-processing to get the inode number and mounted device major/minor numbers of the desired directory (named in   the shell variable `${directory}` as appropriate beforehand), and use `awk` to use the latter twain as a filter on the output of `lsof`:

  ```
  lsof -d cwd | 
  awk '{
      if ($8 == '"`stat --format %i \"${directory}\"`"' \
      &&  $6 == "'"`dc -e \"16doi \`stat --format %D \"${directory}\"\` 100~ r n[,]Pn\"`"'" \
      &&  !x[$2]++)
          print $2;
  }'
  ```

  Run (only) `lsof` as the superuser in order to include other users' processes.
- Use `fuser` as in another answer.

Comment: hmm i'm on a mac and i tried `fstat` it said process not found. i guess that's not really openbsd eh?

Comment: not working for me. i have 2 processes running in the jdk1.8.0_121 folder. `cd /home/ndipiazza/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_121`
lsof -d cwd | awk '{ if ($8 == '"`stat --format %i .`"' && !x[$2]++) print $2; }'
 returns `9445 10167 10168 10170`
yet
`ps -eo pid,args | grep -i /home/ndipiazza/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_121 | awk '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ' '` correctly returns 10133 19113